# Save plot as SVG removing stroke on filled symbols

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, symbols

I have been using filled symbols in ggplot2 and never had any problems exporting to png. However, when I export to svg, for some shapes (triangles and diamonds) one side of the symbol has no stroke.

This initially occurred when I was plotting some maps, so I have tried to replicate the issue with just simple example plots - it's still happening. I can't fathom what is causing one side of the symbols to disappear like this. Is this something I am failing to specify when exporting as svg? Or is there a bug somewhere? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's an example: 
[image]

And the code that created this image:

```
library(tidyverse)

plot = 
  data_frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, group = c("tri", "sq", "tri", "sq", "dia")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y, shape = group)) +
  geom_point(fill = "red", colour = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(23,22,24)) +
  theme_bw()

plot %>% ggsave("test.svg", ., height = 10, width = 10, units = "cm")
```

Note: I have tried using `svglite()` directly to export - same thing happens.

Comment: It is not a proper solution, but you can print points with two layers. The overlaying would be defined as fill = NA, so the stroke will be saved properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug in `svglite`:

[Missing edges in svg file for some point characters when background color is set](https://github.com/r-lib/svglite/issues/92)

First reported on `ggplot2` github:

[ggsave missing edges with some shapes in svg format](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2915)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! That's exactly it. Current workaround seems to be just to use the default `svg()` to save the plot